# Auto-load new items in feed with "Load more"-button

Tags: activity-feed, feed

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhazRn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

So we have a feed with tiles (item requests) that can be interacted with by users, thereby removing them from the feed. Below this feed there is a block with newly added items / products, so the feed has a "load more"-button instead of infinite scroll to make the other content block & the footer accessible.

What makes the most sense regarding adding new item requests in the feed when one / multiple item request(s) is removed?

1. Automatically load a new tile (item request) at the bottom of the feed (below block of newly added items), so there is a constant number of tiles in the feed at all time
2. Only let users load new items in the feed through the "load more button", with the option that the feed is empty if a user has interacted with all the items, unless he clicks "load more"
3. Other solutions?

Comment: do you mind if I purpose another layout for your problem or you just have to stick with this one?

Comment: No feel free to suggest other layouts!

Comment: cool, I'm on it.

Answer (score 1):

You want the user to do as little as possible in order to enjoy the experience. Think about it, when you fill out the form online it is so much nicer and easier and more beautiful if the form switches between one field and another. If you does this automatically you are having so much more of a better experience simply because it is interpreting what you need to do. Asking the user to click to load more doesn’t seem that much inconvenience, but the site that does it automatically when it knows you want to see more seems so much better, wouldn’t you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the layout consistent to avoid as much 'view jumping' as possible, this is part of what makes for a smooth user experience. I'd suggest #1 being a good starting point. When an item gets dismissed, immediately fill the space with a new item and give it a little zing so it gets noticed. This way the tile count is always the same and the view doesn't jump around. Remember to ensure that the container block holding the dismissed item is keep in-place to prevent flow changes due to the removal of a block element.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f03kte.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I believe **simplicity** is a key both for design & development and it seems that your example lack of designing aspect. I can provide further detail if you want me to cause the fundamental intro to the problem is already introduced by you with the question's itself.

Actually layout change will not answering directly to your problem hence, this way you will not have a problem of loading more items or blocks.

PS: Please don't consider the changes on items/names and that's my bad inconsistencies of the shapes. Anyway if you're decided to move with your current layout or not satisfied with it, I have some other ideas with your owns too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to visualize it. But the same issue will still occur in mobile view, how would you deal with it there, as it is a responsive website?

Comment: I'll provide more details abt that whenever I find a chance.

Comment: Pardon me about being not available for a while. Well, my thought is about escaping the crash your design suffering which depends revising it on the medias other than the mobile. There is no any mention about "mobile" solution in your question hence you have point to expect it as well. My choice would be the 1st choice you proposed since then. Because giving the constant number of choices (feed, activity item or whatever) even the user deletes would seem more consistent instead of consumed feed.